# Is it possible/easy to use postgreSQL instead of Redis with Stream-Framework?

Tags: django, stream-framework

How can I tweak [stream-framework](https://github.com/tschellenbach/Stream-Framework) to make it use postgreSQL instead of Redis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually did ask this question directly to the *Stream-Framework* project maintainers on their GitHub Repo and they responded :

> No it's not. You can use either redis or cassandra

Quote from Thierry Schellenbach ( Author Stream-Framework )

https://github.com/tschellenbach/Stream-Framework/issues/204#event-997545923